# Limit cropping on one side?

Tags: crop

I have a workflow that uses one of several tools that crop a generated pdf (either the standalone class with crop=true, or the pdfcrop or dvipng tools). In some cases I want to limit the cropping on one side. Currently, I'm achieving this by doing an `\hspace` then writing a period. That works, but I want to know if there are more elegant solutions. I just verified that (at least with the dvipng method) writing my period in white also works (`\usepackage{xcolor}...\hspace{...}\textcolor{white}.`). I also verified that using `\hphantom` and so on does *not* work: the extra space generated thereby *will* be cropped. Any other ideas about how to achieve this---if possible, without loading the `xcolor` package?

Answer (score 1):

**Use pdfcrop only**

You can do this with `pdfcrop` with no need for the `\hspace` and period.  For example...

```
pdfcrop --margins 10 0 0 0 in.pdf out.pdf
```

will leave a margin of 10 basic points on the left side of your pdf.  The order of the `--margins` values are left, top, right, and bottom.

You can also add a white border to an already cropped pdf.

```
pdfcrop --margins 10 in.pdf out.pdf
```

You can even use a negative margin value to "overcrop", or crop **more** than the white border.  This is especially useful if you need to crop away a box that surrounds your content.

Comment: Thanks, yes this could be an option. In my use-case, though, I have a number of documents where the ink takes up varying space. I want them all to have a constant width. To use the `--margin` flag on pdfcrop, I'd have to determine a different margin width for each. So not ideal for me. But for other workflows, this might be a good option.

Comment: @dubiousjim: I see.  Is it possible for you to simply use the geometry package to create your original PDF already having the correct width?